# JPA Respository: Data return null when @GetMapping include two required param

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Based on my question above, Below is my code.

**UserService**

```
        @Service
        public class UserService {
            @Autowired
            private UserRepository userRepository;

            public List<User> getUserByIdAndEmail(Long id, String email) {
                return userRepository.findByIdAndEmail(id, email);
            }

        }
```

**UserRepository**

```
     @Repository
     public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

        public User findUserByEmail(String email);
        public List<User> findByIdAndEmail(long id, String email);
     }
```

**UserController**

```
        @RestController
        public class UserController {
            @Autowired
            private UserService userService;

            @Autowired
            private ModelMapper modelMapper;

            @GetMapping(path="user/idEmail/{id}/{email}")
            public @ResponseBody UserDto getUserByIdAndEmail(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable String email) {
                return modelMapper.map(userService.getUserByIdAndEmail(id, email), UserDto.class);
            }
        }
```

**User**

```
        @Entity
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Table(name = "idr_user")
        public class User {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;
            private String name;
            private String email;
        }
```

**UserDto**

```
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

And when i enter the correct ID and Email the result is null.

[image]

Can I know which part that I missing?

Comment: Can you include the implementation of modelMapper.map method?

Comment: Why would you expect a list of users from the method query? Is there a posibility for users to have same id? Can you also include, User and UserDto classes?

Comment: @birca123 i already add user and UserDto

Comment: @mrkachariker i already amend my code

Comment: do you have records matching with your criteria you input? both params should match for 
 same row/record in your database.

Comment: @user404 ya, should match, then can display the result

Comment: everything seems fine. What you can do most is set debug pointer or check if you really get the params inside your repository method. What is really being passed in`getUserByIdAndEmail` method. Also, enable query printing for this and run the query from database console too.

Comment: @user404 how to do that ya? im newbie

Comment: just print the variables inside each method of your request calling. match input values and your printing values. Or just do a quick youtube search about "how to set debug pointer in intellij(your Ide)"

Answer (score 0):

Change
`public List<User> findByIdAndEmail(long id, String email);`

to

`public Optional<User> findByIdAndEmail(long id, String email);`

then apply logic if the optional is present.
You shouldn't expect a list in this case as the ID is a primary key, therefor no duplicate. Even if you have duplicated emails, as long as you use id, you won't receive a list.